# Pandas DataFrame: use column value to slice string in another column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a pandas DataFrame as follow:

```
     col1  col2  col3
0    1     3     ABCDEFG
1    1     5     HIJKLMNO
2    1     2     PQRSTUV
```

I want to add another column which should be a substring of `col3` from position as indicated in `col1` to position as indicated in `col2`. Something like `col3[(col1-1):(col2-1)]`, which should result in:

```
     col1  col2  col3       new_col
0    1     3     ABCDEFG    ABC
1    1     5     HIJKLMNO   HIJK
2    1     2     PQRSTUV    PQ
```

I tried with the following:

```
my_df['new_col'] = my_df.col3.str.slice(my_df['col1']-1, my_df['col2']-1)
```

and

```
my_df['new_col'] = data['col3'].str[(my_df['col1']-1):(my_df['col2']-1)]
```

Both of them results in a column of `NaN`, while if I insert two numerical values (i.e. `data['col3'].str[1:3]`) it works fine. I checked and the types are correct (int64, int64 and object). Also, outside such context (e.g. using a for loop) I can get the job done, but I'd prefer a one liner that exploit the DataFrame. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `apply`, because each row has to be process separately:

```
my_df['new_col'] = my_df.apply(lambda x: x['col3'][x['col1']-1:x['col2']], 1)  
print (my_df)
   col1  col2      col3 new_col
0     1     3   ABCDEFG     ABC
1     1     5  HIJKLMNO   HIJKL
2     1     2   PQRSTUV      PQ
```