# python pandas parse string based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing several columns including 'text', 'start', 'tend', and I want to create a new column that extracts a substring of 'text' based on the 'start' and 'tend'.

```
text               start              tend      subtext
'Sample text'        2                 8        'mple te'      
'Sample text'        4                10        'le text'
```

This works:

```
df['subtext']= df['text'].str[2:6]
```

This produces 'nan' instead of text:

```
df['subtext']= df['text'].str[df['start']:df['tend']]
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with passing a series rather than a single value. Any help would be appreciated, and I'm open to another approach if this strategy is bad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395993/pandas-dataframe-use-column-value-to-slice-string-in-another-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`, because each row needs to be process separately:

```
data = {
    
    "text":["sample text","sample text"],
    "start":[2,4],
    "tend":[8,10]
    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['subtext']= df.apply(lambda x: x['text'][x['start']:x['tend']], 1)
```

**Output**

```
    text        start   tend    subtext
   sample text   2       8      ample t
   sample text   4      10      ple tex
```