# How can I best apply pandas str.find to another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

Consider a data frame with a column of strings: `["Good Temperature 14.0", "Bad Temperature 28.0", "Very Odd Temperature -42.3"]`

I can create a new column `df["Ptr"] = df["Data"].str.find("Temperature")` or maybe  `df["Ptr"] = df["Data"].str.find("Temperature") + len("Temperature")` to get the starting point of those floating points.

But now I am stymied. I want to type `df["Data"].str[df["Ptr"]]` but Python says no.... Is there a clever way to do this which doesnt require looping through each row?

Regex?

Thanks,

Comment: IMO, this is the XY problem. You probably don't need `str.find` if you intend to extract the values. Better to use `.str.extractall` with the proper capturing groups. like finding a number with a positive lookbehind of 'Temperature ' for instance

Comment: in the simple scenario with the values at the end of the string, this will work df['Data'].str.rsplit(' ').str[-1]

Comment: Thanks, I was simplifying my question a little but was referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395993/pandas-dataframe-use-column-value-to-slice-string-in-another-column and that is exactly applicable!